# How to get running OSGi container info (name, version etc.) from code?

Tags: java, osgi

I want to detect under which OSGi container my application (bundle) is running. How to do this from java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bundle systemBundle = bundleContext.getBundle(0);
String symbolicName = systemBundle.getSymbolicName();
Version version = systemBundle.getVersion();
```

You can guess the implementation (felix, equinox, ...) from the **symbolicName** and the version from the **version** of the **systemBundle**.

The **id** of the **systemBundle** is always **0**.